# Find destinations or routes where JAL flies its aircrafts other than Boeing 7XY-Z

Tags: japan, aircraft, domestic-travel, jal

I want to find out all flight routes or domestic destinations where Japan Airlines (JAL) uses smaller aircraft (anything except Boeing 7XYZ), especially from Tokyo (both Narita NRT and Haneda HND).

It is okay to take a Boeing flight from Tokyo to location ABC, then a small aircraft to location DEF and similarly on the return leg.

I assume all of them would be domestic journeys only and mostly, the remote regions, not-so-urban cities or far-off islands

For example:
Embraer 170 as E70 - 17 of them
Embraer 190 as E90 - 2 of them
Bombardier RJ-200 as CRJ
Bombardier DHC8
Saab 340B - 12 of them
ATR-42 -

Besides, I won't mind trying any other domestic airline (LCCs are fine as well) in Japan.

I just want to avoid Airbus A320, 321, 330 and Boeing 737, 767, 777, 787.

Airbus 319 and Boeing 757 are fine as well.

Links:

1. https://www.jal.co.jp/en/5971/seatmap/seatmap.html
2. https://www.jal.com/en/outline/aircraft.html
3. https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Japan_Airlines/fleetinfo.php

Comment: So, have to ask...why?  You do realize the A319 is a 3x family member and the 757 and 767 come from a commonality design.  Is it *just* the size?

Comment: @Johns-305, it's about size and age, I want to fly onboard either the small aircrafts or the uncommon (less common today) and about to go extinct aircraft. It's almost impossible to find a 727 in Asia

Answer (score 4):

It's a low-tech solution, but you can download [JAL's flight schedules as PDF](https://www.jal.co.jp/dom/route/time/) and eyeball them manually.  They're Japanese only, but fairly straightforward: the plane type is listed in the second column, everything not starting with `7xx` is a non-Boeing aircraft, and there's a code key on page 9.

Comment: The 国内線時刻表 PDF is so ugly and cramped to look at. I wish JAL has exported the data into an HTML table and simply rendered it with some javascript to help us filter. nevertheless, will look into it.

Comment: The PDF is what they use to print the schedule booklets available at every Japanese travel agent and even on board the planes.

Answer (score 0):

I found some data at openflights for the airline JAL and the airports NRT and HND

1. https://openflights.org/airport/NRT lists HIJ, KMQ
2. https://openflights.org/airport/HND lists GAJ, MSJ, SHM
3. https://openflights.org/airline/JL lists more options

A press article from JAL lists more details
(http://press.jal.co.jp/en/release/201701/004122.html)

Latest release: Bombardiers are being replaced by Embraer jets (http://press.jal.co.jp/en/release/201708/004392.html)

E190:

- Tokyo (Haneda) = Nanki-Shirahama
- Tokyo (Haneda) = Miyazaki
- Osaka(Itami) = Akita
- Osaka(Itami) = Niigata
- Osaka(Itami) = Miyazaki
- Niigata = Sapporo(New Chitose)

E170:

- Fukuoka = Matsuyama
- Fukuoka = Amami Oshima
- Kagoshima = Amami Oshima

ATR42-600:

- Kagoshima = Amami Oshima
- Kagoshima = Yakushima
- Kagoshima = Okinoerabu

Comment: Openflights maintainer here.  Please beware that the route data you're referring to is badly out of date, I'm looking for new sources but not having much luck.

Comment: Hi @jpatokal, i totally understand that openflights data maybe out of date, the airline's website usually works, i tried finding an English version, but couldn't find it yet.